# Accessing ISI Web of Science through SOAP

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I'm trying to write a python script that retrieves information about publications from ISI Web of Science.  I found domoritz's python script [wos.py](https://gist.github.com/domoritz/2012629) on GitHub. It uses Suds to connect to the ISI Web of Science web service.  I've imported it into my python script and I tried this code, following the very brief instructions in the comments:

```
from wos import *
soap = WokmwsSoapClient()
results = soap.search('Hallam')
```

I then get an error:

```
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'line 1:1: unexpected token: Hallam'
```

I looked through the code in wos.py.  Here is the `search` function:

```
def search(self, query):
    qparams = {
        'databaseID' : 'WOS',
        'userQuery' : query,
        'queryLanguage' : 'en',
        'editions' : [{
            'collection' : 'WOS',
            'edition' : 'SCI',
        },{
            'collection' : 'WOS',
            'edition' : 'SSCI',
        }]
    }

    rparams = {
        'count' : 5, # 1-100
        'firstRecord' : 1,
        'fields' : [{
            'name' : 'Relevance',
            'sort' : 'D',
        }],
    }

    return self.client['search'].service.search(qparams, rparams)
```

I thought maybe `query` can't be just a plain python string, as I saw in the [WSDL](http://search.isiknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WokSearchLite?wsdl) page that `userQuery` is actually of type `xs:string`. But [this page](http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/cxf-wsclient-demo/docs/soap/WokSearch/api/search.html) says that `userQuery` "Must be a valid WOKQL query statement. This requirement is enforced internally", which makes it seem like I don't have to pass in a special type.  Anyway, I tried appending `'xs:string'` to the beginning of query but I got the same error.

Does anybody know the proper way to use this method?

Comment: I am also trying to learn how to access web of knowledge data. Do you know what is happening? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647236/soap-service-for-accessing-web-of-knowledge-using-php

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, can't help you there!  I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Thank you! Did you have to ask for any additional permission in order to access the web of knowledge using this system?

Comment: @Daniel I'm also on a computer at a university that has access to Web of Knowledge, and I didn't have to ask for any special permission, it just seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently passing in a python string was fine, but I needed a string that was more like a search query.  I found this example on [the website](http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/cxf-wsclient-demo/docs/soap/WokSearch/api/search.html) I mentioned before:

```
<soap:Body>
  <woksearch:search xmlns:woksearch="http://woksearch.v3.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com">
  <!--  this request has the minimum required elements, 
      but contains all valid retrieve options 
      for this operation and databaseId -->
  <queryParameters>
     <databaseId>WOK</databaseId> 
     <userQuery>AU=Arce, G*</userQuery>      
     <queryLanguage>en</queryLanguage> 
  </queryParameters>
....
```

So I tried using `results = soap.search('AU=Hallam')` and that worked.  I can now do things like `print results.recordsFound` and I get correct answers.

Comment: Today I got this error:
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The Web Service (version 2.0) has been retired permanently. Please contact Thomson Reuters IP and Science Technical Support http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/techsupport/ for information on how to obtain a new version of our Web Service.'

Comment: The Web Service version 2.0 has been replace by version 3.0. Here is the description : http://ipscience-help.thomsonreuters.com/wosWebServicesLite/WebServicesLiteOverviewGroup/Introduction/wsdlFileLocations.html

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use the [`Wos Python Client`](https://github.com/enricobacis/wos) that can be install with:

```
pip install wos
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
from wos import WosClient
import wos.utils

with WosClient('JohnDoe', '12345') as client:
    print(wos.utils.query(client, 'AU=Knuth Donald'))
```

You will also have a CLI tool to be used like:

```
wos -u 'JohnDoe' -p '12345' query 'AU=Knuth Donald'
```

---

*DISCLAIMER: I don't work for Web of Science but I am the author of the client. You need to have web services access (which is a paid service in addition to the normal WOS access) since Web of Science does not allow web services requests coming from normal users. You should ask your university to provide you with the username and password that WOS gave them. This is not just for my client but for anything that uses WOS web service. *

Comment: If I run the command `wos -u 'xxx@xxx.org' -p 'mypassword' connect`, I get `ERROR: No matches returned for Username xxx@xxx.org`. Is the user name not the email address?

Comment: @jordix I'm having the same problem, did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @patti_jane: you need to have web services access (which is a paid service) since Web of Science does not allow web services requests coming from normal users. You should ask your university to provide you with the username and password WOS gave them.

Comment: @enrico.bacis I already have the username and password wos gave, and they work fine when I login to the system but  I receive the same error as jordix mentioned above when I try to access via wos.py

Comment: @patti_jane What do you mean with "login"? You need WWS Premium access, which is not given by default. I'd suggest to check with wos support what level of access you have. Because I just checked and I confirm I can login with my credentials

Comment: @enrico.bacis I thought login credentials and premium access were the same things, now that I have premium access, I tested it with the following query (wos.utils.query(client, 'AU=BUSH KAREN AND PY=(2015 AND 2016)')) however even though WOS returned 9 results, script returned no records?

Comment: I got a vpn access (by user name and password provided by my institution) to web of science, so i can just go to webofknowledge.com and search for any thing i want, but when i try to search through python i got error. I it should be noted that through the same user name and password i can search in scopus and search in scopus by python too.

Comment: Sorry for the negative attitude - I think your contribution, which is probably great, need one more disclaimer in front: Premium access is needed!. Everyone looses time trying to get through authentication. I will be happy to upvote again.

Comment: @jaromrax that's not an additional requirement of the client, but a requirement of the question itself. As an addition, I don't work for web of science and I've never received any money for the project. But sure, I'll add a note, but feel free to leave the downvote, I don't need appreciation for people who have a negative attitude for open source contributor who release there code to the public without getting anything in return.

Comment: @enrico.bacis - you just played the card with bad guy offending a good open source contributor. I am in a Stackoverflow Game. One sentence about Premium access would save me one hour. Whatever great job (2nd time I used this word with you) you did, one or two my mouseclicks is what I can do to contribute. Thanks

Comment: @jaromrax no worries, btw, next time that you are stuck, read the comments, you would have noticed that my note was already there in a comment and on the github repo itself: https://github.com/enricobacis/wos#faq-i-cannot-connect- . Have a nice day!