# SOAP service for accessing web of knowledge using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have been trying to learn how to access the soap services of Web of knowledge using PHP. I am using the code below, which I downloaded from https://gist.github.com/domoritz/2012629.

```
<?php
$auth_url = "http://search.isiknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl";
$auth_client = @new SoapClient($auth_url);
$auth_response = $auth_client->authenticate();

$search_url = "http://search.isiknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WokSearchLite?wsdl";
$search_client = @new SoapClient($search_url);
$search_client->__setCookie('SID',$auth_response->return);

$search_array = array(
'queryParameters' => array(
'databaseID' => 'WOS',
'userQuery' => 'AU=Douglas T*',
'editions' => array(
array('collection' => 'WOS', 'edition' => 'SSCI'),
array('collection' => 'WOS', 'edition' => 'SCI')
),
'queryLanguage' => 'en'
),
'retrieveParameters' => array(
'count' => '5',
'fields' => array(
array('name' => 'Date', 'sort' => 'D')
),
'firstRecord' => '1'
)
);

try{
$search_response = $search_client->search($search_array);
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

print_r($search_response);
?>
```

The code seems to be working. However, the `$search_response` I receive is
"User has no entitlement for this service level - WOKSearchLight". I am trying to access this piece of data from a server that is inside an institution that has access to the web of knowledge, and I am actually connected to web of knowledge using http://apps.webofknowledge.com/UA_GeneralSearch_input.do?product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch&SID=4Dd8nnfofoOm@7@5KH6&preferencesSaved=.

Can anyone tell me what is happening? Do I need an extra permission of the site?

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to register first at http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/info/ws_form/?agree=0&x=31&y=12 and enter your IP address, then it should work I think...

Comment: Is this still valid?

Comment: I think it is - but have a try!